# :string syntax in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm following along with a github project online written in Lua and have come across a variable declaration that I don't seem to understand.

```
    local pPlayerConfig :table = PlayerConfigurations[playerID];
    local statusMessage :string= Locale.Lookup(pPlayerConfig:GetPlayerName());
```

in these cases what does the :string / :table do? Are those like predefined types that override the normal type of string?

Comment: This is not normal Lua

Comment: These are type annotations present in some forks of Lua.  They are needed to facilitate compiled code optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as standard Lua is concerned, that's a compile error. There's a decent chance that this is meant to be a specialized version of Lua with a modified compiler or something. But you'll have to investigate the specific project to find out what's going on (since you neglected to say what project this is, we can't help you with that).

Also, `string` and `table` are the names of standard Lua library components, so they shouldn't be used for local variable names regardless. That may be what the prefix `:` syntax is intended to deal with in this modified version of Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is already answered, I can explain what it means. In typed Lua (used by Roblox), `local identifier: type = value` means that the variable with name `identifier` and value `value` has a type of `type`, but this only works when the variable is `local`. Examples:

`local name: string = "John"`

`local emptyTable: table = {}`